# Prolog function not working

Tags: function, prolog

So I wrote this Facts in test.pl file:

```
bottle(b1).
bottle(b2).
bottle(b3).
bottle(b4).

full(b1,100).
full(b2,750).
full(b3,500).
full(b4,250).
consume(X, Y). :-full(X,Z);Z>=Y.
```

The last line in words:
It should return true if the Y Parameter of consume is less then the bottle has if it is full. But if I query this function I get always as a result true. I'm new to Prolog so it would be kindly if you could explain why the error is appearing and Point me in the right direction how to solve this error.

Comment: You should have received plenty of warnings about "singleton variables" that you chose to ignore.

Comment: Mind that Prolog does not use *functions*, these are *predicates*, that's an important aspect.

Comment: @false Yep indeed I did

Comment: @false why do I receive there a error? consume(bottle(X),Y) :- full(bottle(X),Z);Z<=Y.

Comment: Substitute `<=` by `=<`

Comment: @false ok that worked ty, but i get still a warning "singleton variable" for Z last line , why does it not apply the specific number like 100 for the case bottle1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stray dot.

```
% original
consume(X, Y). :-full(X,Z);Z>=Y.
% modified
consume(X, Y) :-full(X,Z);Z>=Y.
```

Please note that this fixes only the "always true" problem.

Comment: Why do i Need the dot on the right side= Z>=Y.?  @dlask

Comment: It's the syntax of Prolog. Every fact and every rule has to be terminated with a dot.